# htaccess redirect with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hello I'm trying to redirect `/fr/welterweight.php` which is a local folder on my website via apache conf or .htaccess.

To `http://www.bluek.com/fr/welterweight.php?c=france` which is another website I own.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /fr/welterweight.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^welterweight.php$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.bluek.com/fr/welterweight.php?c=france
```

But its not working

Answer (score 2):

This rule should work from site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^fr/welterweight\.php$ http://www.bluek.com/$0?c=france [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it doesnt work.
Giving me an error "This page is being redirected too many times"